# Changing swap space from HDD to SSD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

[image]

While installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I created swap in hard drive which is leading me hang for heavy applications because I have 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: @Veeragandham sai krishna 8GB swap partition should be plenty for 8GB RAM. Create new swap partition on SSD and add path to /etc/fstab in same format as existing swap partition except use new UUID. Add a # in front of existing swap partition path in case you decide to change back later. If you are using hibernation you will want to update /etc/default/grub and do a `sudo update-grub` to update "resume" location in grub.cfg.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to use the SSD drive as the swap space but if the life-span of the device is not a concern for you , you can manually delete your current swap partition and create a new one .

First off you have to unmount the current swap (Check your memory usage since unmounting the swap might cause bottlenecks in your RAM) :

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Then delete your swap file (presumably it's `/swapfile` )

```
sudo rm /swapfile
```

And create a new swapfile in your SSD :

```
fallocate -l 2G /path/to/custom/swapfile/in/ssd   #Change the size to suit your needs
```

then change the permissions :

```
sudo chmod 0600 /your/swapfile
```

make a swap partition :

```
sudo mkswap /your/swapfile
```

and finally mount it :

```
sudo swapon /your/swapfile
```

Now you should be able to use the new swap partition.

And don't forget to change the swap file address in your `/etc/fstab` file to point to the new swap partition not the old one. The line containing `swap` should look like this :

```
/new/swap/location    none    swap    sw    0   0
```

And if you want to use the hibernation feature , you should update your grub config as @C.S.Cameron mentioned :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: OP may also want to update hibernation resume location in grub.cfg

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thanks for pointing out . Updated.